# extract cell values from data frame as inputs into a function

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following data:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1  100
 [2,]  101  200
 [3,]  201  300
 [4,]  301  400
 [5,]  401  500
 [6,]  501  600
 [7,]  601  700
 [8,]  701  800
 [9,]  801  900
[10,]  901 1000
```

I want to print out each cell in the data such that it can be used as an input into another function. For example I want to extract the values at each of the following locations

```
1, 1
1, 2
= 1, 100

2, 1
2, 2
= 101, 200

3, 1
3, 2
= 201, 300

4, 1
4, 2
= 301, 400
```

I can do something like the following:

```
i1 = 1
c(i1, i1)
c(i1, i1 + 1)

c(i1 + 1, i1)
c(i1 + 1, i1 + 1)

c(i1 + 2, i1)
c(i1 + 2, i1 + 2)
```

Which gives me the locations but I want the values and I want to increase the `i1` value. I tried the following:

```
for(i in 1:length(df)){
  from = c(i, i)
  to = c(i, i + 1)
  i = i + 1
  #out = df[from, to]
  #print(out)
}
```

Which didn¡t give me the expected output.

```
Expected output:
```

A function which can store the following values:

```
from = 1
to = 100

from = 101
to = 200

from = 201
to = 300

from = 301
to = 400

...
```

Which can then be passed to other parts of a function.

Data:

```
df = structure(c(1, 101, 201, 301, 401, 501, 601, 701, 801, 901, 100, 
200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000), .Dim = c(10L, 
2L))
```

EDIT:

```
i = NULL
i = 1
for(i in 1:length(range_of_companies_from_to)){
  from = range_of_companies_from_to[i, 1]
  to = range_of_companies_from_to[i, 2]
  i + 1
  out = print(paste(from, to, sep = ", "))
  #out = paste("c(", from, ",", to, ")", sep = "")
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want to perform a `grid search` method. You can use the `crossing()` function of the [`tidyr` package ][1]. What kind of function are you using after ?


  [1]: https://www.tmwr.org/grid-search.html

Comment: Try apply? Semething like: `apply(d, 1, foo)` and your function: `foo <- function(value1, value2){...}`

Comment: The function can just be something simple like `print(from)`, `print(to)` then these values will be passed as a combination i.e. `c(1, 100)`... `c(301, 400)`.

Comment: What does 3,3 or 4,4 mean here? We only have 2 columns?

Comment: ah, yes, it should be `3, 2` and `4, 2`...

Comment: I added some `forloop` which doesn't give me exactly what I wanted but on the right lines (I think)

Comment: The issue is in `length(df)` which gives 20. Change it to `nrow(df)`.